# Filtering many-to-many count expression using existing subquery

Tags: objective-c, core-data, expression

In my app, I have a many-to-many relationship between tags and links as follows :

```
Tags <<-->> Links
```

I am trying to return a list of the tags that relate to links that have the currently active tags, but are not included in the active tags.

I also want to obtain a count of the number of links that have the 'other' tags, which needs to be limited by the active tags.

Using the below, I have been able to return the 'other' tags and a count of links, but the count returned is of all links for each tag.

I would like to be able to count the links using a similar approach to the one I'm using to build the subquery, but am struggling to get it to work. I have tried using the subquery generated in the count NSExpression, but this errors when the subquery is evaluated.

```
// Test array of tag names
self.activeTagArray = [@[@"tag1", @"tag2"] mutableCopy];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[Tag entityName]];

// We want to exclude the tags that are already active
NSPredicate *activeTagsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT ANY name IN %@", self.activeTagArray];

// Build subquery string to identify links that have all of the active tags in their tag set
NSString __block *subquery = @"SUBQUERY(links, $link, ";

[self.activeTagArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id tagName, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    if (index == self.activeTagArray.count - 1) {
        subquery = [subquery stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY($link.tags, $tag, $tag.name = '%@') != NULL", tagName]];
    } else {
        subquery = [subquery stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY($link.tags, $tag, $tag.name = '%@') != NULL AND ", tagName]];
    }
}];

subquery = [subquery stringByAppendingString:@") != NULL"];

NSLog(@"Subquery : %@", subquery);

NSPredicate *noTagsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:subquery];


// Create a predicate array
NSArray *predicateArray = @[noTagsPredicate, activeTagsPredicate, userPredicate];
NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicateArray];

fetchRequest.predicate = compoundPredicate;
fetchRequest.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = @[@"links"];

// Set up the count expression
NSExpression *countExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction: @"count:" arguments:@[[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath: @"links.href"]]];


NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];

expressionDescription.name = @"counter";
expressionDescription.expression = countExpression;
expressionDescription.expressionResultType = NSInteger32AttributeType;

fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[@"name", expressionDescription];

// Sort by the tag name
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *resultsArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

NSMutableArray *allTags = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *tagDict in resultsArray) {
    NSLog(@"Tag name : %@, Link Count : %@", tagDict[@"name"], tagDict[@"counter"]);
    [allTags addObject:tagDict[@"name"]];
}

[allTags addObjectsFromArray:self.activeTagArray];
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't yet understand what exactly you want to count (and what is `links.href`?) An example would be helpful. - But note that you can simplify the `noTagsPredicate` to `SUBQUERY(links, $link, ANY $link.name in %@).@count > 0), self.activeTagArray`, making the enumerateObjectsUsingBlock loop obsolete.

Comment: The loop builds a set of nested subqueries that determines if each of the tags is associated with that link, so the predicate replacement suggested won't do the same thing. The issue is that I am going from Tags, where I identify the active tags I am interested in, to determine the Links they associate with. From there, I go back to Tags from the Links identified to find any other remaining tags for those links that are not in the active set.

Comment: You are right, it is not the same predicate, my fault. (I still think that it can be simplified, but that is not your question.) - So for each fetched (other) tag, you want the count of links of that tag which are related to all given active tags, is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, it's actually a bit tricky to explain what I'm trying to achieve. I want to return a count of the links that have all of the active tags, grouped by each of the other tags. So, if you have 5 tags, tag1, tag2, etc. and tag1 and tag2 are active, I want to count the links that have tag1 and tag2 associated, then return grouped counts for the remaining three tags. Hope that's a bit clearer!

Comment: If I understand it correctly then below code should give that result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the following predicate fetches your "other tags",
i.e. all tags that are related to a link which is related to all of the given "active tags":

```
NSArray *activeTags = @[@"tag1", @"tag2"];

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Tag"];

NSPredicate *p1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT name in %@", activeTags];
NSPredicate *p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(links, $l, SUBQUERY($l.tags, $t, $t.name IN %@).@count = %d).@count > 0",
                   activeTags, [activeTags count]];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p1, p2]];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

And now the "trick": The left hand side of the predicate p2 is

```
SUBQUERY(links, $l, SUBQUERY($l.tags, $t, $t.name IN %@).@count = %d).@count
```

and that is exactly the count of links that should be included in the result,
so we can create the expression description from that predicate:

```
NSExpression *countExpression = [(NSComparisonPredicate *)p2 leftExpression];

NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
expressionDescription.name = @"counter";
expressionDescription.expression = countExpression;
expressionDescription.expressionResultType = NSInteger32AttributeType;

[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"name", expressionDescription]];
```

---

The resulting SQLite query is quite complex. It might be sensible to fetch the links first:

```
NSFetchRequest *linkRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Link"];
NSPredicate *linkPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(tags, $t, $t.name IN %@).@count = %d",
                              activeTags, [activeTags count]];
[linkRequest setPredicate:linkPredicate];
NSArray *activeLinks = [context executeFetchRequest:linkRequest error:&error];
```

and fetch the tags in a separate step, which can be done with above code where only the
predicate `p2` is replace by the simpler subquery

```
NSPredicate *p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(links, $l, $l IN %@).@count > 0", activeLinks];
```

Comment: The first solution worked perfectly! I was hesitant to try and bring back the link managed objects, as there is a likelihood that there could be thousands and I wasn't sure whether iterating over them would be slower than a single SQLite query to the database.

Comment: @robotpukeko: It actually took me some time to figure this out, so I am glad that it helped!

Comment: As an update, I also tested implementing the second method of fetching the links first, which worked, but the initial retrieval of my test data set of 3,500 links was very slow. Subsequent queries with active tags were fast, but still not as efficient as the initial method suggested.