# predicate subquery to return items by matching tags

Tags: core-data, tags, many-to-many, subquery, predicate

I have a many-to-many relationship between two entities; Item and Tag. I'm trying to create a predicate to take the selectedItem and return a ranking of items based on how many similar tags they have. So far I've tried:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(itemToTag, $item, $item in %@).@count > 0", selectedItem.itemToTag];
```

Any other iterations that have failed. It currently only returns the selectedItem in the list. I've found little on Subquery. Is there a guru out there that can help me refine this?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Edited 9June

The good news is with Dan's code I'm able to populate the tableview with items! Unfortunately ranking numbers are 0.

**Solution**
I originally tried searching for tags by ID rather than name. Note the two predicate options in 'rankingExpressionDescriptionForTags:' I do not have unique identifier to my tags and use the second of the two options. Thanks Dan!

Comment: It seems very similar to [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040722/predicate-to-rank-related-items-by-matching-tag-keyword), if somewhat more refined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A predicate is only the beginning.

First take a look at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117765/filtering-many-to-many-count-expression-using-existing-subquery) VERY similar question.

Assuming your model has an `Item` and `Tag` entities, related in a many-to-many relationship:
`Item.tags` <<-->> `Tag.items`

The answer:

```
- (NSExpressionDescription*) rankingExpressionDescriptionForTags:(NSSet*)tags
{
    NSPredicate* p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(tags,$t,$t IN %@).@count > 0",tags];
    //if your tags are not unique (meaning you only like to match the names of tags)
    //change the predicate to:
    //p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(tags,$t,$t.tagName IN %@).@count > 0",[tags valueForKey:@"tagName"]];
    NSExpression* rankExpresion = [(NSComparisonPredicate*)p2 leftExpression];
    NSExpressionDescription* rankExpDesc = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
    rankExpDesc.name = @"ranking";
    rankExpDesc.expression = rankExpresion;
    rankExpDesc.expressionResultType = NSInteger64AttributeType;
    return rankExpDesc;
}

- (NSExpressionDescription*) objectIDExpressionDescription
{
    NSExpressionDescription* expDesc = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
    expDesc.name = @"objectID";
    expDesc.expressionResultType = NSObjectIDAttributeType;
    expDesc.expression = [NSExpression expressionForEvaluatedObject];
    return expDesc;
}

- (NSFetchRequest*) rankingRequestForItem:(NSManagedObject*)item
{
    NSFetchRequest* r = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Item"];
    NSPredicate* p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != %@",item.objectID];
    r.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
    r.propertiesToFetch = @[[self objectIDExpressionDescription],
                            [self rankingExpressionDescriptionForTags:[item mutableSetValueForKey:@"tags"]]];
    r.predicate = p;
    return r;
}
```

**Note:**

1. The resulting array contains dictionaries
2. **(AFAIK) You will have to sort the resulting array in-memory after the fetch if you like to sort by ranking**
3. You **cannot** use a fetched results controller to track changes in these objects
4. You can use a FRC to display these items

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I segue to the tableview the app closes and returns 'Unresolved error (null), (null)'. I'm still a newbie and may be missing something obvious. Similar reported issues may point to managedobjectcontext. Is there something I've missed here?

Comment: What is the exact error message? add an exception breakpoint and see what line cause the exception.

Comment: I've tracked it down to in viewdidload I've got:     NSError *error;
 if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
  // Update to handle the error appropriately.
  NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
  exit(-1);

Comment: I found that I never enter the nsexpressiondescription. I've included it as property and synthesize it. What do I need to enter it?

Comment: It looks like you have another problem, your `fetchedResultsController` might be returning `nil`. You need to include it where you need to use the request. it does not have to be a property.

Comment: After long hours and no progress I've got two stupid questions. 1. does all this live in a fetchedresultscontroller? and 2. If I include nsexpressiondescription where the request is does that mean it's used with the request. I really want this to work but am struggling make it work in my .m file.

Comment: You can see an example [HERE](https://github.com/infradust/ItemsAndTags). As you will see, you will probably want to avoid using a FRC as you will want to sort your results by ranking ... This is getting a bit off topic

Comment: I integrated it in this morning with items populating in the list. Ranking showed 0 for everything, but I'll work with it and keep you posted. Thanks for the link I can't thank you enough!

Comment: Data generation in the sample is random, it could be that there was no match with other items, run it a few times and see if there is a difference (the store is deleted on each run).

Comment: I've spent hours troubleshooting and I think 'rankingRequestForItem' isn't recognizing my managedobject. I've tracked it through the code and it's takes a similar path to yours but still shows 0. Dan, I'd hate to bug you again, but any final issues I could investigate?

Comment: First, your `configureCell` method has a bug, as it try to get a `NSManagedObject` out of the FRC, while it holds `NSDictionary`s. If you provide a log print of your selected item, and another print of ALL other items in your store so I can have an idea of what kind of results you expect I might be able to help (small sample data would suffice).

Comment: I did a log at numberOfRowsInSection for nsfrc and it comes out as: <NSFetchedResultsController: 0x8d6f0e0>. print log at selected item shows the item and shows the datamodel's to tag relationship and to manufacturer relationship. let me know what else i can provide. - selected item:
<Item: 0x8ceb460> (entity: Item; id: 0x8ce85e0 <x-coredata://33361226-C2B9-4B1A-8EE9-8026E11E405B/Item/p3> ; data: {
    itemName = Mustang;
    itemToManufacturer = "0x8cdbdd0 <x-coredata://33361226-C2B9-4B1A-8EE9-8026E11E405B/Manufacturer/p4>";
    itemToTag = "<relationship fault: 0x8cd5ce0 'itemToTag'>";

Comment: I meant you should log the content of the selected item: `NSLog(@"selected name: %@, tags: %@",selected.itemName,[selected.itemToTag valueForKey:@"tagName"]);` and then print ALL items in the store bt fetching them in a request `[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Item"]` execute it directly on the context `NSArray* items = [context executeFetchRequest...]` and then in the same way log all the other items

Comment: Dan, this code is awesome! Thanks again. As usual I'm struggling, but this time it's to sort. As an FYI i've added a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225496/how-to-sort-array-from-fetch-by-valueforkey