# Predicate subquery for products associated by tag

Tags: core-data, many-to-many, subquery, relationship, predicate

I have a datamodel in core data as such:

```
Store <--->> Product <<--->> Tag
```

I'm looking to create a query that matches products based on their associated tags. A typical use scenario would be you choose to search storeA and output storeB. By selecting storeA a list of storeA products is presented. Let's say you pick productA from the list which brings you to a second viewcontroller. That second viewcontroller lists all relating productB's (because earlier you set storeB as output). I'm following this: [predicate subquery to return items by matching tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103508/predicate-subquery-to-return-items-by-matching-tags) but want the added store filter of products. Is subquery the way to go? How would I include a filter by selected Store?

Comment: can't you simply change the predicate in `rankingRequestForItem` to `@"SELF != %@ AND store = %@",item.objectID,item.store.objectID`?

Comment: great! seems simple but when i add it i get - property 'store' not found on object of type 'NSManagedObject*' :(. Does this change to NSManagedObjectContext since i'm dealing with item and store?

Comment: the `store` is what i would call my reverse relationship from `Product` to `Store`, change it to whatever name that represent that in your `Product` entity ...

Comment: It worked! I created the relationship and added the 'store' managedObject to the method rankingRequestForItem. Thanks for the help, greatly appreciated! Could you add as an answer?