# how to sort array from fetch by valueForKey

Tags: arrays, sorting, core-data, nsdictionary, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a fetchResultController that compiles an array by running through multiple methods. The final cells display a name and number (ranking). I'd like to take the cells from the tableview and sort them by the number (ascending). I've tried nssortdescriptor in the frc but run into issues when I try to call the 'ranking' because it isn't a keypath of the entity I'm fetching. Is there a place I can intercept this array that comes out of the frc to sort by valueForKey:@"ranking"? How would I implement this sort?

The methods it cycles through to create the valueForKey is here:

```
- (NSExpressionDescription*) rankingExpressionDescriptionForTags:(NSSet*)itemToTag
{
    NSPredicate* p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(itemToTag,$t,$t.tagName IN %@).@count > 0",[itemToTag valueForKey:@"tagName"]];
    NSExpression* rankExpresion = [(NSComparisonPredicate*)p2 leftExpression];
    NSExpressionDescription* rankExpDesc = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
    rankExpDesc.name = @"ranking";
    rankExpDesc.expression = rankExpresion;
    rankExpDesc.expressionResultType = NSInteger64AttributeType;

    return rankExpDesc;
}

- (NSExpressionDescription*) objectIDExpressionDescription
{
    NSExpressionDescription* expDesc = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
    expDesc.name = @"objectID";
    expDesc.expressionResultType = NSObjectIDAttributeType;
    expDesc.expression = [NSExpression expressionForEvaluatedObject];
    return expDesc;
}

- (NSFetchRequest*) rankingRequestForItem:(Item*)item 
{
    NSFetchRequest* r = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Item"];
    NSPredicate* p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != %@",item.objectID];
    r.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;


    r.propertiesToFetch = @[[self objectIDExpressionDescription],@"itemName",
                            [self rankingExpressionDescriptionForTags:[item mutableSetValueForKey:@"itemToTag"]]];


    r.predicate = p;
    r.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"itemName" ascending:YES]];


    return r;
}
```

and the frc with cell config is here:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSLog(@"selected item: %@, itemToTag: %@",selectedItem.itemName,[selectedItem.itemToTag valueForKey:@"tagName"]);
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self rankingRequestForItem:selectedItem];
    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".


    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}


- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",[item valueForKey:@"itemName"],[item valueForKey:@"ranking"]];
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I explained [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103508/predicate-subquery-to-return-items-by-matching-tags/24104718?noredirect=1#comment37410578_24104718), there is no way (AFAIK) to sort based on the `ranking` expression. You will have to sort the results in-memory, thus nullifying completely the need for a FRC.

Simply execute the request on the given context and sort in-memory:

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSFetchRequest* r = [self rankingRequestForItem:selectedItem];
NSArray* results = [context executeFetchRequest:r error:&error];
NSSortDescriptor* sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"ranking" ascending:NO];
results = [results sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sd]];
```

The `results` array will now hold your sorted information, use it as a datasource for your table.
Store the `results` in a view controller property like:

```
self.results = results;
```

This code might go in your `viewDidLoad` method for example.

everywhere you access the FRC to get an object, you now access your table datasource for that information (assuming you have only 1 section):

```
NSIndexPath* someIndexPath = //some index path you might get as parameter
[self.results objectAtIndex:someIndexPath.row]; //return NSDictionary
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. The above method goes in numberOfRowsInSection, right? From there it walks through the methods, but I get 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' when it hits 'results = [results sortedArrayUsing...' (i've added @"ranking"). Am I way off here? If 'results' is generated in the table datasource what configureCell should I use to recognize it?

Comment: No, this construct your datasource (like the code you now have in your `fetchedResultsController` method). see my edit. You should learn how to debug your code, or at least read the full error description returned. 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' is a partial description of an error, and in a general case, no one can help you unless you explain the error better. when a method does not work the way you expect, read its documentation (like [THIS](http://goo.gl/nW7Ztx))

Comment: It works! Thanks Dan this is great. Just to confirm, does majority of the code (everything but nsindex...) goes in viewDidLoad? It works there now. Greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: @user3411663 Yes, but it could be converted to "lazy loading" the same way the original `fetchedResultsController` property was implemented ...